# Responsive Video Youtube for Prestashop

Tags: html, iframe, youtube, prestashop

I have problem with Including video in Prestashop!

This is the code I use to Include the video:

```
<div class="videoWrapper">
 <iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3G1PFLuTrgM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.videoWrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
    padding-top: 25px;
    height: auto  !important;
}
.videoWrapper iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

But Is not working at all!

Anyone has any idea what can I do?

Thanks!

Comment: It is working for me. Anyway, you should try using Bootstrap utilities: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#responsive-embed

Comment: You should definitely look for fitVid.js library :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change default inline width and height :

```html
<div class="videoWrapper col-md-12">
 <iframe width="100%" height="450" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3G1PFLuTrgM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Using Bootstrap is useful and easy, try to add height to your iframe using CSS (or keep default)